# How Bulk Creation of Custom Objects can be implemented?

Tags: custom-object, bulkification, bulk, create

How Bulk Creation of Custom Objects can be implemented?

Assuming we need to replicate and debug a case where there are 3000 custom objects in the customer org. To replicate this situation, we could create as many custom objects as we could. However, it takes a lot of time to create single object.

Is there any way to automate this or create many objects at once?

Answer (score 1):

There could be several ways to automate sobject creation, if we need to create multiple custom objects.

If you use SFDX, it is possible to use `shane` plugin to create custom object metadata file and then deploy those files or create a package from them and install the package.

```
upperlim=2000

for ((i=0; i<=upperlim; i++)); do
   echo "$i"
   sfdx shane:object:create -t custom -l "CustomObject$i" -p "CustomObjects$i" -a "CustomObject${i}__c" 
done
```

Another option is to use Metadata API and create them in Apex

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    HttpResponse res = MetadataApiCustomObjectCreate.add('CustomObject' + i);
    System.debug(res.getBody());
}
```

with use of the following class

```
public without sharing class MetadataApiCustomObjectCreate {
   private static String getSoapBodyXml(String name) {
        return ''
            + '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
            + '<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'
            + '<env:Header>'
            + '<urn:SessionHeader xmlns:urn="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">'
            + '<urn:sessionId>' +  UserInfo.getSessionId() + '</urn:sessionId>'
            + '</urn:SessionHeader>'
            + '</env:Header>'
            + '<env:Body>'
            + '<createMetadata xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">'
            + '<metadata xsi:type="CustomObject">'
            + '<label>' + name + '</label>'
            + '<pluralLabel>' + name +'s' + '</pluralLabel>'
            + '<fullName>' + name + '__c' + '</fullName>'
            + '<nameField><label>Name</label><type>Text</type></nameField>'
            + '<deploymentStatus>Deployed</deploymentStatus>'
            + '<sharingModel>ReadWrite</sharingModel>'
            + '</metadata>'
            + '</createMetadata>'
            + '</env:Body>'
            + '</env:Envelope>'
        ;
    }

    public static HttpResponse add(String name) {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint(URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/m/50.0');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        req.setHeader('SOAPAction', '""');
        req.setBody(getSoapBodyXml(name));
        return new Http().send(req);
    }
}
```